# launchd login script doesnt work

Tags: launchd, launch-agent

I write the following plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.foo.foo1</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/Users/Shared/fooscript.sh</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I add this plist file in /Library/LaunchAgents (so for all users).

the script (stored in /Users/Shared/)

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/rm -rf /Users/Shared/filetodelete.docx
```

I try launchctl load com.foo.foo1.plist but nothing.
I reboot my mac, but nothing.
The file filetodelete.docx is on the mac.

the script has all rights 777
the com.foo.foo1.plist file has -rw-r--r--  (like all user plist files)

What could be the reason?

Comment: Do you get any output when you run launchctl load com.foo.foo1.plist ?

Comment: nothing.... I get nothing that is my problem :(

Comment: Run $launchctl list and check output. Do you see your agent in list ?

Comment: yes. I see it. 
I see the agent, I can run the script manually.All should be fine, but it isn't fine.